# Enable “save image” in iOS web application

Tags: ios, iphone-web-app, iphone-standalone-web-app

Added this to my site:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

While most people ask how to disable the callout in a fullscreen web-app, I need to enable it.

I will basically have a slider containing iPhone wallpapers, so I want to **enable** users to save the image, just like they would do in regular Safari.

[Here's my demo](http://icosmin.com/w/), you'd need to add it to your homescreen and then open it from there. Saving images is disabled - why?

Is this even possible?

NOTE: specifying `-webkit-touch-callout: inherit;` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solution help you?

[Save Image touch menu gone with iOS6 web apps.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627350/save-image-touch-menu-gone-with-ios6-web-apps)

Ir requires you to have a second domain, but it could probably just be a subdomain (?)

GOod luck!