# Save Image touch menu gone with iOS6 web apps.

Tags: ipad, safari, ios6, iphone-web-app

With the iOS6 update, the "Save Image" touch popup menu is now gone when users are in a website that has **apple-mobile-web-app-capable** enabled. This is really important for my website http://2048px.com.

We want users to be able to add the site to their home screen. The way that users obtain new wallpaper is to click on the download button and then use the Save Image touch menu to save it to their camera roll. But like I said, in iOS6 the "Save Image" option seems to be gone when the webapp is being used.

Does anyone know of some magic meta tag to turn this back on? Or maybe a fancy way to save an image to the camera roll directly.

Answer (score 0):

While I never found a solution to get the save image button back, I did find a solution. I noticed that if I opened a link in a new tab and the url to the link was an external domain, the link would open in Safari instead of the webapp. On my site, all my image for download are now being hosted on an external domain on S3. I then make the download links open in a new tab only when the website is in webapp mode. I accomplish this with the following code.

```
if (window.navigator.standalone) {
    $('a.download').attr({target:'_blank',href:orig_download});
}
```